# How could i query operation log(Oplog) in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

I want to query the oplog to find what are the operation made in a particular time.
How it possible to find and query oplog in MongoDB. Where oplog is placed? Please explain with an example...I could'nt find any tutorial over internet...

Comment: It's just a collection and also only present with replica sets. The manual is your best place to read: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple query to read from oplog

```
 query = {'ts': {'$gt': some_timestamp}}  # Replace with your own query.
        cursor = db.oplog.rs.find(query, **_TAIL_OPTS)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to query by date, you need to generate a proper MongoDB timestamp. You can use the `Date` class for that purpose.

If you want for example to count the amount of entries between two dates, you can try a query similar to this one:

```
db.oplog.rs.count(
    {
        ts: 
        {
            $gt: Timestamp(new Date("2020-02-01").getTime() / 1000, 1), 
            $lt: Timestamp(new Date("2020-03-01").getTime() / 1000, 1)
        }
    }
);
```

You have to always divide the `Date` milliseconds by `1000`, because the `Timestamp` class operates with seconds after `1970-01-01`.

Here is another example query which excludes some very usual entries in the `oplog`, like e.g `"periodic noop"`:

```
db.oplog.rs.find(
    {
        ts: 
        {
            $gt: Timestamp(new Date("2020-02-01").getTime() / 1000, 1), 
            $lt: Timestamp(new Date("2020-03-01").getTime() / 1000, 1)
        },
        "o.msg":
        {
            $ne: "periodic noop"
        },
        "ns" : {
            $ne: "config.system.sessions"
        }
    }
).limit(5).pretty();
```